# Fundamental group of $\mathbb T^2 \vee S^1$, the torus and circle intersecting at a point

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

> Compute the fundamental group of the space, X, made up of the two-dimensional
> torus, $\mathbb T^2$, and the one dimensional circle, $S^1$, when they intersect at one point.

Let $x_0$ be the point of intersection. I want to apply Von-Kampen theorem's, so I have to decompose $X$ as a union of open path connected sets $U$ and $V$, with $x_0\in U\cap V$.

As the set $U$, I would take an open cube of size a little bit bigger than the torus $\mathbb T^2$ and intersect it with $X$, thus obtaining the torus plus two small segments emerging from $x_0$. And for the set $V$, I would take an open ball centered at the center of $S^1$ and with a radius a little bit bigger and intersect it with $X$, obtaining then the circle $S^1$ plus a small area of the torus in the neighborhood of $x_0$. Both $U,V$ are path connected.

The intersection $U \cap V$ would be then a small area in the torus around $x_0$ plus two segments emerging from $x_0$. This intersection is also path connected and it deforms continuously to the point $x_0$. Moreover, the set $U$ also deforms into the torus, as well as the set $V$ deforms into $S^1$. Hence, we get that $\pi_1(X,x_0) \cong (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z )* \mathbb Z$

**Is this solution correct?** I also wonder if there is any better way to write this exercise. At this point this kind of argumentation seems too informal, especially the part about deforming figures into simpler ones. Is there any way to rise a little bit the formality of this type of argument?

Any help or advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Just as a note: Let $X, Y$ be two connected CW-complexes or two connected topological manifolds. Then $\pi_1(X\lor Y)\cong \pi_1(X)*\pi_1(Y)$. Idea: Any point of a CW-complex or topological manifold has a contractible neighborhood.